# Camel way: JSON to Array of Object

Tags: json, jackson, apache-camel

Need to deserialize stringls like "[100,200]" into array of Integer to later use from:

```
<to uri="class:java.awt.Robot?method=mouseMove&amp;multiParameterArray=true"/>
```

**multiParameterArray=true** is a key.

```
<unmarshal ref="json"/>
```

with

```
<dataFormats>
    <json id="json" library="Jackson" allowJmsType="true"/>
</dataFormats>
```

and stuck. Working in restricted environment, can't create custom beans that perform the stuff. Need some standard camel way.

**UPDATE 1**
Seems this construct does exactly what I need. But I'd better use  `<unmarshal/>` rather then it

```
<setBody>
  <constant>[100,200]</constant>
</setBody>
<setBody>
    <jsonpath>$.*</jsonpath>
</setBody>
```

Comment: sorry this is a confusing question. Can you try to better explain what you need, and maybe show some sample data.

Comment: Thanks for answering, @ClausIbsen It's confusing, coz some editor "helped" me ;) and edited original question. I'll fix it now.

Comment: Check now please. Basically what I need is just to turn JSON arrays into array of integers used by **multiParameterArray**